# Relative paths from subdomain - HTML

Tags: html

This seems like a simple question but it's baffling me. Let's say my domain is:
bar.com and my subdomain is foo.bar.com.

If I'm on foo.bar.com/1/2  and I go back a directory through a link with a relative path (href="../") it will take me to foo.bar.com, not foo.bar.com/1 as I'd expect it to. Why is this? How do I get to foo.bar.com/1 with a relative path?

**Side question:** If foo.bar.com is masking another directory (let's say bar.com/foo, and I go to href="/", will that take me to the root of the entire domain (bar.com) or just to the root of the subdomain (foo.bar.com)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the current page is `http://foo.bar.com/1/2`, browser thinks `2` is a document under the directory `1`. So if you have `../`, it goes to its parent directory, which is the root directory. If you want to link to `http://foo.bar.com/1/`, you can use `href=./`.

I don't quite understand your side question. Generally if the URL displayed in browser is `bar.com/foo`, then `href="/"` takes users to `bar.com/`; if the URL displayed in browser is `foo.bar.com/`, then `href="/"` takes users to `foo.bar.com/`

Comment: Great, thank you! Yes, I think you understood the side question correctly. I didn't realize the ./ trick. I'll try it out and let you know.